# For Wav2Vec2, in the Wav2Vec2PreTrainedModel class, how does the _init_weights(self, module) method know what "module" is?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

The code for the class looks as follows:

```
class Wav2Vec2PreTrainedModel(PreTrainedModel):
    """
    An abstract class to handle weights initialization and a simple interface for downloading and loading pretrained
    models.
    """

    config_class = Wav2Vec2Config
    base_model_prefix = "wav2vec2"
    supports_gradient_checkpointing = True
    _keys_to_ignore_on_load_missing = [r"position_ids"]

    def _init_weights(self, module):
        """Initialize the weights"""
        # gumbel softmax requires special init
        if isinstance(module, Wav2Vec2GumbelVectorQuantizer):
            module.weight_proj.weight.data.normal_(mean=0.0, std=1)
            module.weight_proj.bias.data.zero_()
            nn.init.uniform_(module.codevectors)
        elif isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
            # Slightly different from the TF version which uses truncated_normal for initialization
            # cf https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/5617
            module.weight.data.normal_(mean=0.0, std=self.config.initializer_range)
        elif isinstance(module, (nn.LayerNorm, nn.GroupNorm)):
            module.bias.data.zero_()
            module.weight.data.fill_(1.0)
        elif isinstance(module, nn.Conv1d):
            nn.init.kaiming_normal_(module.weight.data)

        if isinstance(module, (nn.Linear, nn.Conv1d)) and module.bias is not None:
            module.bias.data.zero_()
```

Nowhere is `module` defined.

Further down this method is called for example in `Wav2Vec2ForCTC` in the last line:

```
class Wav2Vec2ForCTC(Wav2Vec2PreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)

        self.wav2vec2 = Wav2Vec2Model(config)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.final_dropout)

        if config.vocab_size is None:
            raise ValueError(
                f"You are trying to instantiate {self.__class__} with a configuration that "
                "does not define the vocabulary size of the language model head. Please "
                "instantiate the model as follows: `Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained(..., vocab_size=vocab_size)`."
                "or define `vocab_size` of your model's configuration."
            )
        self.lm_head = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, config.vocab_size)

        self.init_weights()
```

How does it work if nothing is passed to the method?